Учусь писать тг ботов на telebot, столкнулся с проблемой при работе со списками и кнопками
list = ['apple']

@bot.message_handler(commands=["deleteitems"])
def delete(message):
     keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
     button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(list[0])
     keyboard.add(button1)
     bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите что вам нужно удалить',reply_markup=keyboard) 
     if message.text==list[0]:
          list.remove(0)
          bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Предмет удалён из списка')
     else:
          ()

Вот фрагмент кода, команда которого не работает. Проще говоря, у человека есть корзина, куда он складывает продукты, и этой командой должны появляться кнопки со всеми продуктами из списка, при нажатии на которые, из списка эти значения должны удаляться.
Вопрос тут задаю впервые, поэтому извиняюсь если не корректно сформулировал.

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

Что у вас конкретно не работает?
